# Densely defined operator with compact resolvent

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

If for $a,c\in\mathbb{R}$ we consider the PDE
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+cu_x+au
$$
on $(-L,L)$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions, we can make the ansatz $v=e^{\alpha x}u$ with $c=2\alpha$ to get the transformed equation
$$
v_t=v_{xx}+(a-\alpha²)v.
$$

Its linear operator $\mathcal{L}$ is symmetric.

> > Show that $\mathcal{L}\colon H^2([-L,L])\to L^2([-L,L])$ is densely defined with compact resolvent (i.e. $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\colon L^2([-L,L])\to L^2([-L,L])$ is a compact operator with dense range).

(1) I do not understand the i.e. statement in parantheses. Is this some implication or equivalence to the statement before?

(2) How to prove the statement? As a hint it is asked why $L^2([-L,L])$ is a Hilbert space and that one can use the fact that the spectrum of a compact operator is finite or tends to $0$ if it is infinite.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure they meant "(i.e. $\mathscr L^{−1}:L^2([−L,L])\rightarrow H^2([−L,L])$ is a compact operator with dense range).", not "(i.e. $\mathscr L^{−1}:L^2([−L,L])\rightarrow L^2([−L,L])$ is a compact operator with dense range).". And yes, I'm almost positive that they're equivalent definitions.

Since the spectrum of $L$ is the set of all $\lambda$ such that $\lambda I-L$ does not have an inverse that is a bounded linear operator, and the spectrum of a compact operator is finite or tends to zero if it is infinite, you must use the property that the resolvent is compact.

Take my answer with a grain of salt; it's been a while since I've taken these classes.

Comment: Their operator $\mathcal{L}$ is the forward operator from $H^2\subset L^2$ to $L^2$, which would be the differential operator $\mathcal{L}u=u_{xx}+(a-\alpha^2)u$. The resolvent $(\mathcal{L}-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is compact as an operator from $L^2$ to $L^2$, but is not compact into $H^2$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts How can we prove that the resolvent is indeed compact as an Operator from $L^2([-L,L])$ to itself? I could not manage that.

Comment: There is an orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions for $L$--namely $\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\sin(n\pi x/L)$. The resolvent can be written in this basis, and you'll see that the resolvent has the form $R(\lambda)f=\sum_n c(\lambda,n) (f,e_n)e_n$ where $c_n(\lambda,n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, which is a compact operator.

Comment: May I ask how you get the eigenfunctions? My idea would be to solve $\mathcal{L}u=\lambda u$, i.e. $u_{xx}+(a-\alpha^2-\lambda)u=0$ to get the Eigenvalue $\lambda$. To do so, I have to solve the characteristic equation $k^2=\lambda+\alpha^2 -a$, getting the two Solutions $k_1=+\sqrt{\lambda+\alpha^2 -a}$ and $k_2=- \sqrt{\lambda+\alpha^2 -a}$. Depending on whether the discriminant is negative or non-negative, I get different General Solutions.